# WP_Query - `category__not_in` not working when showing sticky posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to show the first 4 sticky posts that do not have the `videos` category and this is my current loop:

```
<?php $videos_cat_id = get_cat_ID('videos');

$args = array(
    'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'category__not_in' => $videos_cat_id,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
);

$featured_loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($featured_loop->have_posts()) : 
    while ($featured_loop->have_posts()) : $featured_loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 m-bottom p-left-none p-right-none">
            <?php get_template_part('card-featured') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
 endif; ?>
```

But I'm still seeing posts with the `videos` category rendered. I'm not entirely sure why this loop isn't respecting `category__not_in`, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

---

you may need to supply an array value in `category__not_in`. And since `get_cat_ID()` function returns string/int, you may need to this -> `'category__not_in' => array($videos_cat_id)`

Comment: I tried this approach before submitting the question, but it still showed posts of the `videos` category.

Comment: Is the video category slug exactly `videos`?

Comment: Yup, spelled `videos` (triple-checked)

Comment: I "solved" it temporarily by adding a `featured` category to all posts with the `videos` category and then loop through those. Not exactly what I initially wanted but does the trick.